# How to disable automatic door locking in Toyota Aqua (Prius C)

Tags: toyota, keyless-entry, central-locking

I have a Toyota Aqua (2015 model) vehicle which has keyless entry function. It has function where when I comes closer to the vehicle, it automatically unlocks the doors and unfolds side mirrors.

This is very annoying because every time I move around the car, it unlocks and locks again and again. So I want to disable that function. How can I do that?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.toyota.com/owners/resources/warranty-owners-manuals/prius-c/2015

Page 515 in your owners manual.

Comment: We dislike link-only answers, because links can disappear. Better is to copy the text from the relevant page. This enables the reader to see the answer here on SE, and in addition allows web crawlers to index the actual words which answer the question or solve the problem, thus facilitating others' search for information. You can use the "blockquote" icon (next to the URL link icon) in the composition box to import copied text.

Comment: Jupiter, I checked the manual. Since I'm very new to these kind of smart vehicles. I'm bit confused. Can you give me exact steps to do?. Ex. 1. Press this button and hold for these seconds. 2. Put shift leaver to D position. Like that

Comment: You are right. This is one of the most confusing manuals to understand. I'm having a hard time copying the text, but it does say that this is a dealer only settings change. If you look on page 515 you will see a "0" which means dealer only.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica thank you I'll keep that in mind. I will leave the link up for Nishn256 to confirm my observation.